# Debian update to Buster, iptables throwing an error in

Tags: debian, iptables, netfilter

I've just updated my old Debian Jessie server to Buster, and I'm having some issues with iptables.
I understand that the backend has been changed with the update, but I have absolutely no knowledge or experience with any of this.

Running `sudo journalctl -e -u netfilter-persistent.service` gives me the following error

```
Jul 22 16:49:35 systemd[1]: Starting netfilter persistent configuration...
Jul 22 16:49:35 netfilter-persistent[1069]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables start
Jul 22 16:49:35 netfilter-persistent[1069]: iptables-restore v1.8.2 (nf_tables): Chain 'MASQUERADE' does not exist
Jul 22 16:49:35 netfilter-persistent[1069]: Error occurred at line: 6
Jul 22 16:49:35 netfilter-persistent[1069]: Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
Jul 22 16:49:35 netfilter-persistent[1069]: run-parts: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables exited with return code 2
Jul 22 16:49:35 netfilter-persistent[1069]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables start
Jul 22 16:49:35 netfilter-persistent[1069]: ip6tables-restore: line 8 failed
Jul 22 16:49:35 netfilter-persistent[1069]: run-parts: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables exited with return code 1
Jul 22 16:49:35 systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 22 16:49:35 systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 22 16:49:35 systemd[1]: Failed to start netfilter persistent configuration.
```

Below is my iptables

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Sep 12 09:39:51 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 12 09:39:51 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Sep 12 09:39:51 2018
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [5:200]
:INPUT ACCEPT [5:200]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5:680]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [5:680]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 12 09:39:51 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Sep 12 09:39:51 2018
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [5:200]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5:680]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 12 09:39:51 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Sep 12 09:39:51 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [5:200]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5:680]
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 12 09:39:51 2018
```

Commenting out lines 6 and 7 results in this error

```
Jul 22 16:43:38 systemd[1]: Starting netfilter persistent configuration...
Jul 22 16:43:38 netfilter-persistent[663]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables start
Jul 22 16:43:38 netfilter-persistent[663]: iptables-restore: line 8 failed
Jul 22 16:43:38 systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 22 16:43:38 netfilter-persistent[663]: run-parts: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables exited with return code 1
Jul 22 16:43:38 netfilter-persistent[663]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables start
Jul 22 16:43:38 systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 22 16:43:38 netfilter-persistent[663]: ip6tables-restore: line 8 failed
Jul 22 16:43:38 systemd[1]: Failed to start netfilter persistent configuration.
Jul 22 16:43:38 netfilter-persistent[663]: run-parts: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables exited with return code 1
```

I have also tried using update-alternatives to go back to the legacy iptables, but doing that gives me another error

```
Jul 22 16:52:44 systemd[1]: Starting netfilter persistent configuration...
Jul 22 16:52:44 netfilter-persistent[1130]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables start
Jul 22 16:52:44 netfilter-persistent[1130]: iptables-restore v1.8.2 (legacy): iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'nat'
Jul 22 16:52:44 netfilter-persistent[1130]: Error occurred at line: 2
Jul 22 16:52:44 netfilter-persistent[1130]: Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
Jul 22 16:52:44 netfilter-persistent[1130]: run-parts: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables exited with return code 2
Jul 22 16:52:44 netfilter-persistent[1130]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables start
Jul 22 16:52:44 netfilter-persistent[1130]: ip6tables-restore: line 8 failed
Jul 22 16:52:44 netfilter-persistent[1130]: run-parts: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables exited with return code 1
Jul 22 16:52:44 systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 22 16:52:44 systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 22 16:52:44 systemd[1]: Failed to start netfilter persistent configuration.
```

Trying to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` gives me the following error

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up netfilter-persistent (1.0.11) ...
Job for netfilter-persistent.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status netfilter-persistent.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript netfilter-persistent, action "restart" failed.
● netfilter-persistent.service - netfilter persistent configuration
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/netfilter-persistent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-07-22 16:57:09 CEST; 13ms ago
  Process: 1498 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1498 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 22 16:57:09 netfilter-persistent[1498]: iptables-restore v1.8.2 (legacy): iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'nat'
Jul 22 16:57:09 netfilter-persistent[1498]: Error occurred at line: 2
Jul 22 16:57:09 netfilter-persistent[1498]: Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
Jul 22 16:57:09 systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 22 16:57:09 netfilter-persistent[1498]: run-parts: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables exited with return code 2
Jul 22 16:57:09 netfilter-persistent[1498]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables start
Jul 22 16:57:09 systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 22 16:57:09 netfilter-persistent[1498]: ip6tables-restore: line 8 failed
Jul 22 16:57:09 netfilter-persistent[1498]: run-parts: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables exited with return code 1
Jul 22 16:57:09 systemd[1]: Failed to start netfilter persistent configuration.
dpkg: error processing package netfilter-persistent (--configure):
 installed netfilter-persistent package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iptables-persistent:
 iptables-persistent depends on netfilter-persistent (= 1.0.11); however:
  Package netfilter-persistent is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package iptables-persistent (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 netfilter-persistent
 iptables-persistent
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have no idea what I'm doing in here, and the research I've done says to either "fix the rules.v4 file" or to revert to the legacy alternative. Neither seems to work, and I don't know enough to understand what's going on in rules.v4 enough to fix it.

Thanks

EDIT: `apt-cache policy` on request

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=buster-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=10,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     release v=10.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

Output of `dpkg -l  | egrep -v '^ii'`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version                              Architecture Description
+++-===============================-====================================-============-===============================================================================
rc  acl                             2.2.53-4                             amd64        access control list - utilities
rc  avahi-daemon                    0.6.31-5                             amd64        Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD daemon
rc  dpkg-dev                        1.19.7                               all          Debian package development tools
rc  libapt-inst1.5:amd64            1.0.9.8.4                            amd64        deb package format runtime library
rc  libass5:amd64                   0.10.2-3                             amd64        library for SSA/ASS subtitles rendering
rc  libav-tools                     6:11.12-1~deb8u1                     amd64        Multimedia player, encoder and transcoder
rc  libavahi-compat-libdnssd1:amd64 0.6.31-5                             amd64        Avahi Apple Bonjour compatibility library
rc  libavahi-core7:amd64            0.6.31-5                             amd64        Avahi's embeddable mDNS/DNS-SD library
rc  libavcodec53:amd64              6:0.8.21-0+deb7u1                    amd64        Libav codec library
rc  libavcodec56:amd64              6:11.12-1~deb8u1                     amd64        Libav codec library
rc  libavdevice53:amd64             6:0.8.21-0+deb7u1                    amd64        Libav device handling library
rc  libavdevice55:amd64             6:11.12-1~deb8u1                     amd64        Libav device handling library
rc  libavfilter2:amd64              6:0.8.21-0+deb7u1                    amd64        Libav video filtering library
rc  libavfilter5:amd64              6:11.12-1~deb8u1                     amd64        Libav video filtering library
rc  libavformat53:amd64             6:0.8.21-0+deb7u1                    amd64        Libav file format library
rc  libavformat56:amd64             6:11.12-1~deb8u1                     amd64        Libav file format library
rc  libavresample2:amd64            6:11.12-1~deb8u1                     amd64        Libav audio resampling library
rc  libavutil51:amd64               6:0.8.21-0+deb7u1                    amd64        Libav utility library
rc  libavutil54:amd64               6:11.12-1~deb8u1                     amd64        Libav utility library
rc  libbind9-80                     1:9.8.4.dfsg.P1-6+nmu2+deb7u20       amd64        BIND9 Shared Library used by BIND
rc  libbind9-90                     1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u16               amd64        BIND9 Shared Library used by BIND
rc  libbluray1:amd64                1:0.6.2-1                            amd64        Blu-ray disc playback support library (shared library)
rc  libcdio-cdda1                   0.83-4.2                             amd64        library to read and control digital audio CDs
rc  libcdio-paranoia1               0.83-4.2                             amd64        library to read digital audio CDs with error correction
rc  libcdio13                       0.83-4.2                             amd64        library to read and control CD-ROM
rc  libcryptsetup4:amd64            2:1.6.6-5                            amd64        disk encryption support - shared library
rc  libdaemon0:amd64                0.14-6                               amd64        lightweight C library for daemons - runtime library
rc  libdirac-encoder0:amd64         1.0.2-7.1                            amd64        open and royalty free high quality video codec - encoder library
rc  libdirectfb-1.2-9:amd64         1.2.10.0-5.1                         amd64        direct frame buffer graphics - shared libraries
rc  libdns-export100                1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u16               amd64        Exported DNS Shared Library
rc  libdns100                       1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u16               amd64        DNS Shared Library used by BIND
rc  libdns88                        1:9.8.4.dfsg.P1-6+nmu2+deb7u20       amd64        DNS Shared Library used by BIND
rc  libevent-2.0-5:amd64            2.0.21-stable-2+deb8u1               amd64        Asynchronous event notification library
rc  libfakeroot:amd64               1.23-1                               amd64        tool for simulating superuser privileges - shared libraries
rc  libffi5:amd64                   3.0.10-3+deb7u2                      amd64        Foreign Function Interface library runtime
rc  libgcrypt11:amd64               1.5.0-5+deb7u6                       amd64        LGPL Crypto library - runtime library
rc  libgdbm3:amd64                  1.8.3-13.1                           amd64        GNU dbm database routines (runtime version)
rc  libgeoip1:amd64                 1.6.2-4                              amd64        non-DNS IP-to-country resolver library
rc  libgnutls-deb0-28:amd64         3.3.30-0+deb8u1                      amd64        GNU TLS library - main runtime library
rc  libgnutls26:amd64               2.12.20-8+deb7u5                     amd64        GNU TLS library - runtime library
rc  libhogweed2:amd64               2.7.1-5+deb8u2                       amd64        low level cryptographic library (public-key cryptos)
rc  libiceutil34                    3.4.2-8.2                            amd64        Ice for C++ misc utility library
rc  libiceutil35:amd64              3.5.1-6+b3                           amd64        Ice for C++ misc utility library
rc  libicu52:amd64                  52.1-8+deb8u7                        amd64        International Components for Unicode
rc  libirs-export91                 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u16               amd64        Exported IRS Shared Library
rc  libisc-export95                 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u16               amd64        Exported ISC Shared Library
rc  libisc84                        1:9.8.4.dfsg.P1-6+nmu2+deb7u20       amd64        ISC Shared Library used by BIND
rc  libisc95                        1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u16               amd64        ISC Shared Library used by BIND
rc  libisccc80                      1:9.8.4.dfsg.P1-6+nmu2+deb7u20       amd64        Command Channel Library used by BIND
rc  libisccc90                      1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u16               amd64        Command Channel Library used by BIND
rc  libisccfg-export90              1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u16               amd64        Exported ISC CFG Shared Library
rc  libisccfg82                     1:9.8.4.dfsg.P1-6+nmu2+deb7u20       amd64        Config File Handling Library used by BIND
rc  libisccfg90                     1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u16               amd64        Config File Handling Library used by BIND
rc  libjasper1:amd64                1.900.1-debian1-2.4+deb8u5           amd64        JasPer JPEG-2000 runtime library
rc  libjson-c2:amd64                0.11-4                               amd64        JSON manipulation library - shared library
rc  libllvm3.5:amd64                1:3.5-10                             amd64        Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, runtime library
rc  liblogging-stdlog0:amd64        1.0.4-1                              amd64        easy to use and lightweight logging library
rc  liblognorm1:amd64               1.0.1-3                              amd64        Log normalizing library
rc  liblwres80                      1:9.8.4.dfsg.P1-6+nmu2+deb7u20       amd64        Lightweight Resolver Library used by BIND
rc  liblwres90                      1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u16               amd64        Lightweight Resolver Library used by BIND
rc  libmodule-build-perl            0.422400-1                           all          framework for building and installing Perl modules
rc  libmpc2:amd64                   0.9-4                                amd64        multiple precision complex floating-point library
rc  libmysqlclient18:amd64          5.5.60-0+deb8u1                      amd64        MySQL database client library
rc  libnettle4:amd64                2.7.1-5+deb8u2                       amd64        low level cryptographic library (symmetric and one-way cryptos)
rc  libnss-mdns:amd64               0.10-6                               amd64        NSS module for Multicast DNS name resolution
rc  libopencv-core2.3               2.3.1-11+deb7u4                      amd64        computer vision core library
rc  libopencv-core2.4:amd64         2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u2                amd64        computer vision core library
rc  libopencv-imgproc2.3            2.3.1-11+deb7u4                      amd64        computer vision Image Processing library
rc  libopencv-imgproc2.4:amd64      2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u2                amd64        computer vision Image Processing library
rc  libopenjpeg2:amd64              1.3+dfsg-4.8                         amd64        JPEG 2000 image compression/decompression library
rc  libopenjpeg5:amd64              1:1.5.2-3                            amd64        JPEG 2000 image compression/decompression library - runtime
rc  libopenvg1-mesa:amd64           10.3.2-1+deb8u1                      amd64        free implementation of the OpenVG API -- runtime
rc  liborc-0.4-0:amd64              1:0.4.22-1                           amd64        Library of Optimized Inner Loops Runtime Compiler
rc  libpgm-5.1-0                    5.1.118-1~dfsg-1                     amd64        OpenPGM shared library
rc  libpng12-0:amd64                1.2.50-2+deb8u3                      amd64        PNG library - runtime
rc  libpod-latex-perl               0.61-2                               all          module to convert Pod data to formatted LaTeX
rc  libpostproc52                   6:0.git20120821-4                    amd64        FFmpeg derived postprocessing library
rc  libprocps0:amd64                1:3.3.3-3+deb7u1                     amd64        library for accessing process information from /proc
rc  libprocps3:amd64                2:3.3.9-9+deb8u1                     amd64        library for accessing process information from /proc
rc  libprotobuf7                    2.4.1-3                              amd64        protocol buffers C++ library
rc  libprotobuf9:amd64              2.6.1-1                              amd64        protocol buffers C++ library
rc  libpsl0:amd64                   0.5.1-1                              amd64        Library for Public Suffix List (shared libraries)
rc  libqt4-network:amd64            4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64        Qt 4 network module
rc  libqt4-sql:amd64                4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64        Qt 4 SQL module
rc  libqt4-xml:amd64                4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64        Qt 4 XML module
rc  libqtcore4:amd64                4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64        Qt 4 core module
rc  libqtdbus4:amd64                4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64        Qt 4 D-Bus module library
rc  librtmp0:amd64                  2.4+20111222.git4e06e21-1+deb7u1     amd64        toolkit for RTMP streams (shared library)
rc  libschroedinger-1.0-0:amd64     1.0.11-2.1                           amd64        library for encoding/decoding of Dirac video streams
rc  libsdl1.2debian:amd64           1.2.15-10+b1                         amd64        Simple DirectMedia Layer
rc  libsnappy1                      1.1.2-3                              amd64        fast compression/decompression library
rc  libsodium13:amd64               1.0.0-1                              amd64        Network communication, cryptography and signaturing library
rc  libswscale2:amd64               6:0.8.21-0+deb7u1                    amd64        Libav video scaling library
rc  libswscale3:amd64               6:11.12-1~deb8u1                     amd64        Libav video scaling library
rc  libsystemd-login0:amd64         215-17+deb8u7                        amd64        systemd login utility library (deprecated)
rc  libtasn1-3:amd64                2.13-2+deb7u5                        amd64        Manage ASN.1 structures (runtime)
rc  libtcl8.5:amd64                 8.5.17-1                             amd64        Tcl (the Tool Command Language) v8.5 - run-time library files
rc  libtiff4:amd64                  3.9.6-11+deb7u11                     amd64        Tag Image File Format (TIFF) library (old version)
rc  libts-0.0-0:amd64               1.0-11                               amd64        touch screen library
rc  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:amd64         0~git20131104-1.1                    amd64        Texture compression library for Mesa
rc  libva-drm1:amd64                1.4.1-1                              amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- DRM runtime
rc  libva-x11-1:amd64               1.4.1-1                              amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- X11 runtime
rc  libva1:amd64                    1.4.1-1                              amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- runtime
rc  libvpx1:amd64                   1.3.0-3+deb8u1                       amd64        VP8 and VP9 video codec (shared library)
rc  libwebp5:amd64                  0.4.1-1.2+b2                         amd64        Lossy compression of digital photographic images.
rc  libx264-123:amd64               2:0.123.2189+git35cf912-1            amd64        x264 video coding library
rc  libx264-142:amd64               2:0.142.2431+gita5831aa-1+b2         amd64        x264 video coding library
rc  libxtables10                    1.4.21-2+b1                          amd64        netfilter xtables library
rc  libzeroc-ice34                  3.4.2-8.2                            amd64        Ice for C++ runtime library
rc  libzeroc-ice35:amd64            3.5.1-6+b3                           amd64        Ice for C++ runtime library
rc  libzmq3:amd64                   4.0.5+dfsg-2+deb8u1                  amd64        lightweight messaging kernel (shared library)
rc  mumble-server                   1.2.8-2                              amd64        Low latency encrypted VoIP server
rc  mysql-common                    5.5.60-0+deb8u1                      all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
rc  perl-modules                    5.20.2-3+deb8u12                     all          Core Perl modules
rc  proftpd-basic                   1.3.4a-5+deb7u1                      amd64        Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - binaries
rc  rsync                           3.1.3-6                              amd64        fast, versatile, remote (and local) file-copying tool
rc  sgml-base                       1.29                                 all          SGML infrastructure and SGML catalog file support
rc  tcl8.5                          8.5.17-1                             amd64        Tcl (the Tool Command Language) v8.5 - shell
rc  tsconf                          1.0-11                               all          touch screen library common files
rc  udev                            241-7~deb10u4                        amd64        /dev/ and hotplug management daemon
rc  update-inetd                    4.43                                 all          inetd configuration file updater
rc  xml-core                        0.18+nmu1                            all          XML infrastructure and XML catalog file support
```

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, but perhaps or could be because Debian buster uses nftables by default as backend. I recommend you temporarily disable your iptables rules, do the upgrade and convert your rules to nftable rules

Comment: Thanks, but I have no idea what to do. I've never touched iptables directly, and I've got no idea how to convert them to nftable.

Comment: If you don't know anything about these rules, are you sure they're needed? At first sight, they all say ACCEPT, so nothing is being blocked. I can't understand them much either...

Comment: Wait, so am I good to just get rid of them all?
I've not touched this at all, it was like this when I got the VPS.

Comment: I recommend to flush your firewall so it doesn't have any rules, accept all connections in any direction and do testing. Note that if your server runs any container technology, it should take care of the NAT rules itself in the firewall. This way you can see whether these rules are just leftovers or actually needed for some applications

Comment: I genuinely am not knowledgable enough to be able to diagnose this properly. Like I have no idea what's needed and what's not, but honestly I have no idea what iptables is even *doing*. I've literally never touched any of this before even slightly, you're assuming I know a deal more than I actually do.

I commented out the entire file for both .v4 and .v6, and it seemed to not throw an error anymore. No idea what the things in there were trying to do or how to apply them again though. I'm so confused.

Comment: `apt-cache policy` please. Did you upgrade from jessie direct to buster and skipped the releases that lies between them?

Comment: Yes, direct from jessie to buster. I've added that to the main post.

Comment: Not a smart Idea. `dpkg -l  | egrep -v '^ii'`

Comment: :(
Added the output of that

Answer (score 0):

How did  you loose udev and acl? Backup your important date first.

```
mkdir $HOME/apt-download && cd $HOME/apt-download
```

Then we draw the packages with wget

```
wget -c http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/systemd/udev_241-7~deb10u4_amd64.deb
```

and

```
wget -c http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/iptables-persistent/netfilter-persistent_1.0.11_all.deb
```

and

```
wget -c http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/acl/acl_2.2.53-4_amd64.deb
```

Install all with

```
sudo dpkg -i netfilter-persistent_1.0.11_all.deb udev_241-7~deb10u4_amd64.deb acl_2.2.53-4_amd64.deb
```

Only if no errors

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install
```

when apt and dpkg are free

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: Right, done that. I had to comment out rules.v6, but once I did that everything passed without errors.

The error seems to be gone now, though it looks like rules.v4 has been totally overwritten by something else. Whatever it is everything seems to work fine.

Thank you!